# How to use lifeCyle and setState in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

> this is app.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todo_lists: [
        { id: 1, name: "Hoc React" },
        { id: 2, name: "Hoc HTML" },
        { id: 3, name: "Hoc Jquery" },
        { id: 4, name: "Hoc CSS" }
      ],
      showList : []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    let {showList, todo_lists} = this.state
  this.setState({
    showList : [...todo_lists]
  })
  console.log(showList)
  }
}
```

> when console.log(showList) on browser it return empty array like this [], clearly I assigned  showList : [...todo_lists] in setState. help me

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :**

```
// this.setState is async method
this.setState({
    showList : [...todo_lists]
}); 
console.log(showList) // <--- this will not give you updated value right after
```

---

you can use `this.setState` `callback` method for that, it is being called right after the state is set

```
this.setState({
    // showList : [...todo_lists]
    showList : this.state.todo_lists.map(todo => ({ ...todo}))
},() => {
    console.log(this.state.showList) //<------ Check here
})
```

**Suggestion :**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.todos = [
        { id: 1, name: "Hoc React" },
        { id: 2, name: "Hoc HTML" },
        { id: 3, name: "Hoc Jquery" },
        { id: 4, name: "Hoc CSS" }
    ]
    this.state = {
      todo_lists: this.todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo})),
      showList : this.todos.map(todo => ({...todo}))
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Reactjs.org

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

So what you wrote will NOT happen immediately, and your console.log will NOT get the right values immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that React's setState is an async method, so it may delay the update in favor of perceived improvement in performance.

What you ***could*** do, is something like this *(if you don't want to use the callback provided by the setState)*:

```
componentDidMount() {

  const {showList, todo_lists} = this.state,
    nextShowList = [...todo_lists];

  this.setState({
    showList: nextShowList
  });

  console.log(nextShowList); // executes immediatelly

}
```

If you **want to** use the callback provided by the setState method, simply use it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {

   const {showList, todo_lists} = this.state;

   this.setState({
     showList: [...todo_lists]
   }, () => console.log(this.state.showList)); // MAY NOT execute immediately

}
```

Also, as an additional tip (if I may), use the first argument as a function, or you may have problems setting your todo_list!

```
componentDidMount() {

  this.setState(prevState => {

    return {
      showList: [...prevState.todo_lists]
    };

  }, () => console.log(this.state.showList));

}
```

Again, for the same reason: Since setState is async, you can't guarantee that the this.state **outside** of the setState is up-to-date!